# How do I get rid of these lines in my mesh?

Tags: mesh

It's near where I merged objects. I've tried mesh>clean up>merge by Distance but that didn't work. Any tips?
[image]

Comment: you could try this: select one of your 2 meshes, press ctrl F > Intersect (Boolean), and choose Union in the Operator box

Comment: @moonboots Okay if I make an answer from that? :)

Comment: yes you can, did it work?